# VBA excel macro to transpose a specific matrix

Tags: vba

I'm new to VBA excel and I'm trying to code a macro that would convert a table like the following:

```
Time    Station1
0       150.0
60      250.0
200     450.0
250     650.0
...     ...
```

into a transpose table like that with the values immediately following:

```
Time 0 60 200 250 ... Station1 150.0 250.0 450.0 650.0
```

So far I have been using some transpose function but I need to know the size in advance.

[edit]

I was using the following code with the table in B2:C6

```
Sub Worksheet_Change()

Set Target = ActiveCell
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
[B2:C6].Copy
[E2].PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Target.Select

End Sub
```

It's more or less copying/pasting by hand..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please show us what you've tried.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for welcoming me on this platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using `Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose()`, you don't need to know the size of the variant array. However if you are referring to the Last used rows in the two columns, then give the following code a try.

In your case, you can try two variant arrays to get the **multiple rows into multiple columns in one row**.

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub rowsToColumns()
Dim vCol1 As Variant, vCol2 As Variant
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim WS As Worksheet

Set WS = Sheets(2)
lastRow = WS.Cells(WS.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
'--since data starting with row 2
lastRow = lastRow - 1
vCol1 = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WS.Range("B2").Resize(lastRow).Value)
vCol2 = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WS.Range("C2").Resize(lastRow).Value)

'-- output to sheet
WS.Range("B10").Resize(1, UBound(vCol1)) = vCol1
WS.Range("B11").Resize(1, UBound(vCol2)) = vCol2

End Sub
```

**Sheet view:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks bonCodigo. It's more elegant and flexible.