# Excel VBA Union

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel 2010, how do I create a two column range from two separate ones using VBA?

The code below uses Union, but the combined range (rngAll) only contains the first column (rng1):

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rngAll As Range

Set rng1 = Range(TableColumn1)
Set rng2 = Range(TableColumn2)
Set rngAll = Application.Union(rng1, rng2)
```

Thanks.

Comment: What are TableColumn1 and 2?

Comment: They are table references defined in the input variable of a function e.g. ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("Table[Column_Name]")

Comment: Could you just Union the two of them?

Comment: When I try to Union both of them I only get the first column in the new range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this by qualifying the `Range` object with `Sheet`:

```
Set rng1 = Sheets(1).Range(TableColumn1)
Set rng2 = Sheets(1).Range(TableColumn2)
Set rngAll = Application.Union(rng1, rng2)
```

Then in the `Watch Window` or `Immediate Window`, you may check the `rngAll.Address`. It should show you both the ranges.

Comment: Thanks for your reply bonCodigo.

It is part of function that when tested in a sub procedure qualifies rng1 and rng2 fully; does this make a difference?

Comment: Please try and let us know if it's working. Otherwise community can help you to find some other avenue.

Comment: OK, I see that the address shows both ranges, so thanks. How do I then pass the new two column range to an array also with two columns?

Comment: You can use `WorksheetFunction.Transpose` to pass a `range` to an `array`. See [this post for a sample code.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070487/vba-excel-macro-to-transpose-a-specific-matrix/15070638#15070638)